# Custom types as functions: Construct a function from another named function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, construct, custom-type

I am trying to create my own custom type, which is not simply an object, but a function.

I am trying to achieve the following result, in which functions super1 and super2 are constructed by a function by name Super.

```
function Super() {}         // fill in missing parts here...
const super1 = new Super(); // fill in missing parts here...
const super2 = new Super(); // fill in missing parts here...
console.log(super1, super1.constructor, super1.constructor === Super); // yields: [Function: super1] [Function: Super] true
console.log(super2, super2.constructor, super2.constructor === Super); // yields: [Function: super2] [Function: Super] true
```

I basically want to be able to detect if a given function was constructed by a particular other function or not, in the above example, if functions super1 and super2 were constructed by function Super or not.

I am trying to mimic similar behavior of basic JavaScript types:

```
const date = new Date();
console.log(date, date.constructor, date.constructor === Date); // yields: [Function: date] [Function: Date] true
```

Any ideas...

Comment: So what exactly are you asking here? Is the code you have there not working as you expect it to do?

Comment: @Cerbrus, the code I wrote is incomplete, hence the comments about filling in missing parts. The code I wrote, the console.log statements on super1 and super2 in particular, do not do what the comment says. I was hoping someone could inspire me to fill in the missing parts for the log statements to work properly. I also added a similar example but with standard a JS type Date, which works similar to what I want to achive with my custom type.